# python subprocess cannot read output of airodump-nd mon0

Tags: python, subprocess, aircrack-ng

Hi I am trying to get output of

```
airodump-ng mon0
```

where mon0 is monitor mode of my wireless interface.
I want to read the output of the command continuously without killing the process in certain time interval

My code is as follow:

```
import subprocess
import time

airodump = subprocess.Popen(['airodump-ng','mon0'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          universal_newlines=True
                        )
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]:
    time.sleep(10)
    o_file = airodump.stdout
    x = o_file.read()
    print(x)
airodump.kill()
```

It seems like program gets stuck at **x = o_file.read()**.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When setting both `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` there's a risk of deadlock (unless you use `communicate` to read both channels together), because if the process writes on standard error and you're trying to read standard output, both block forever.

In your case, you want to control the reading, so `communicate` isn't an option. I suspect that you just want to merge both streams so change:

```
stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

by

```
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
```

to redirect standard error to standard output and get all output+error in `o_file.stdout`

Aside: `for i in [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]:` would be more "pythonic" like: `for _ in range(5):` since you're not using `i`, and also imagine that you want to loop 10000 times :)

But that doesn't solve your problem if your application isn't printing the lines at once in all cases, because `read()` is blocking, and you need it to stop exactly when you want, so I would:

- create the process
- create a thread to read the lines in a loop, with a shared boolean to be able to stop the read (because killing the process isn't enough if there are lines in the output buffer)
- wait some time
- set the boolean to `True` & terminate the process

Like this:

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading

stop_output = False

def f(p):
    global stop_output
    while True:
        l = p.stdout.readline()
        if not l or stop_output:
            break
        print(l.rstrip())   # or whatever you want to do with the line

airodump = subprocess.Popen(['airodump-ng','mon0'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                      universal_newlines=True
                    )
t = threading.Thread(target=f,args=(airodump,))
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
# kill the process and stop the display after 10 seconds whatever happens
airodump.terminate()
stop_output = True
```

Comment: sorry it didnt helped. :( . I placed stderr=subprocess.STDOUT instead of stderr=subprocess.PIPE but it still stucks on read.

Comment: the problem is if process doesn't have anything to read but is still running, it will also be stuck.

Comment: Hi @jean can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074734/airodump-ng-output-with-python-subprocess-popen-coummunicate-method

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing just trying different approach. But nothing is working out. I need  data of running airodump-ng in certain interval and use it to display on webpage(updating page on each interval).