# airodump-ng output with python subprocess.Popen coummunicate method

Tags: python, subprocess, aircrack-ng

Hi I am trying to get continuous output from **airodump-ng mon0**

For that reason I was trying to read the output of **airodump-ng mon0** after certain time with Popen.communicate but still cannot get anything.

```
import subprocess

airodump = subprocess.Popen(['airodump-ng', 'mon0'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    o_airodump, unused_stderr = airodump.communicate(timeout=15)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    airodump.kill()
    o_airodump, unused_stderr = airodump.communicate()
    print(o_airodump)
    print(unused_stderr)
```

When I run this it gets stuck at:

```
o_airodump, unused_stderr = airodump.communicate()
```

I am totally stuck now. And unable to find any other ways. Please help.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I solved the issue by dumping the output to a file (use airodump feature to dump to a file) and I read the file with python periodically(lets say every 5 or 10 second). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to retreive the list of avaible wifi networks after 60 seconds:

```
def find_wifi(interface):
    table = ''
    stdout = []
    timeout = 60
    table_start = re.compile('\sCH')
    start_time = time.time()

    airodump = subprocess.Popen(['airodump-ng', interface], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)

    while time.time() < start_time + timeout:
        line = airodump.stdout.readline()
        if table_start.match(line):
            table = ''.join(stdout)
            stdout = []
        stdout.append(line)
    airodump.terminate()
    print(table)
```